# Uuencode / Uudecode library for .NET or for Visual C++ 6.0?

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I have some files that are uuencoded, and I need to decode them, using either .NET 2.0 or Visual C++ 6.0. Any good libraries/classes that will help here? It looks like this is not built into .NET or MFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uudeview, [here](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Software/UUDeview/). It is an open source library which works well and will also handle yenc files in addition to uuencoded ones. You can use it with C/C++ or write an interop wrapper for C# without much trouble.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is C code. Also, the author seems to have taken both UUEncoding and writing/documenting his library surprisingly seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Code Project has a .NET library + source code for uuencoding/decoding.  The actual algorithm itself is quite widely disseminated over the web and is quite short.

The Code Project link:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/TextCoDec.aspx

Short intro from the article:

> This article presents a class library
>   for encoding/decoding files and/or
>   text in several algorithms in .NET.
>   Some of the features of this library:
>
> Encoding/decoding text in Quoted
>   Printable Encoding/decoding files and
>   text in Base64 Encoding/decoding files
>   and text in UUEncode Encoding/decoding
>   files in yEnc

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but thought I would post my response in case anyone else comes across it.

[I wrote a Stream based implementation of uuencoding](https://github.com/awalsh128/Awalsh128.Text) for both the encoder and decoder with extensive unit tests.

To decode any stream:

```
using (Stream encodedStream = /* Any readable stream. */)
using (Stream decodedStream = /* Any writeable stream. */)
using (var decodeStream = new UUDecodeStream(encodedStream))
{ 
    decodeStream.CopyTo(decodedStream);
    // Decoded contents are now in decodedStream.
}
```

To encode any stream:

```
bool unixLineEnding = // True if encoding with Unix line endings, otherwise false.
using (Stream encodedStream = /* Any readable stream. */)
using (Stream decodedStream = /* Any writeable stream. */)
using (var encodeStream = new UUEncodeStream(encodedStream, unixLineEnding))
{
    decodedStream.CopyTo(encodeStream);
    // Encoded contents are now in encodedStream.
}
```

Comment: how can i use this? is there any dll for this?

Comment: and it is always throwing Index out of range exception in my case where line length is 61 chars