# How to Decode UUENCODE

Tags: vb.net

I have a project that i am getting an XML file that has an embedded PDF file that is encode in UUencode. Is there anyway to do this in VB.net? Any help would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uuencode / Uudecode library for .NET or for Visual C++ 6.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879621/uuencode-uudecode-library-for-net-or-for-visual-c-6-0)

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate, but if you were to Google this, you find about 200 possible solutions.

Comment: I am not able to get that sample working on the decode file i have. I am getting an error that it could not find a part of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a win32 uudecode.exe available for free:

http://www.bastet.com/

HTH

Comment: I can't get any of the function working that I found online working.