# Uuencoded image to byte array

Tags: c#, uuencode

How do I convert uuencoded image to byte array?

My image is encoded like this:

```
begin 644 image.jpg
M_]C_X``02D9)1@`!``$`8`!@``#__@`?3$5!1"!496-H;F]L;V=I97,@26YC
********************** MANY LINES ***************************
MH`R]:TM=9TJ^TIK_`%32UO8#`;_1;V33=5M,E6\VQOH@9+:<8P)$!(!8=Z`,
M#P;X#T+P-!J"Z2=1O+_5[E+S6=<UO4)]6UW6+B-#%!)J&HW)\R46\1,<$2+'
/#&&=EC\V6:20`[.@#__9
`   
end
```

I would like to get byte array without need to save image on hdd first. After decoding I will save it directly into DB.

Comment: Do you know what the 644 stand for ? is that an unix permission ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the first and last line, many solutions here, [RegEx are funny :o)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Then [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method should do the trick.

**Edit**

I was wrong since [uuencode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) is not [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

You will have to find a third-party implementation.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879621/uuencode-uudecode-library-for-net-or-for-visual-c-6-0) or [here.](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2005/12/18/63486.aspx)

Or maybe use a native library like [active template library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69d7t73b.aspx).

Comment: `Convert.FromBase64String` looks like is exactly what Im looking for thanks. Should I remove new lines `\n` from data too?

Comment: Yes you have to remove the new lines characters. "\r\n" or whatever, you should probably use Environment.NewLine property : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I still cant decode the data. I think its because I have data in Uuencode format and `Convert.FromBase64String` expects data in Base64. For example Base64 contains only alphanumeric characters plus `+` and `/` as you can see my data is not in that format. I think Uuencode can be converted to Base64 in some way and maybe then I can use `Convert.FromBase64String` method but still I dont know how or if its the right way.